# Writing tablet compatible with Mac

Tags: hardware-recommendation, handwriting

I need to write mathematics, but I would like to avoid Latex for quick notes that I wish to send to colleagues. So I would like to have somewhere to write with some sort of pen, in such a way that

1. What I write appears on the display of my computer (please note that I don't have an iPad, just a MacBook)
2. It gets saved on my computer when I finish.

These are just quick notes, so no special drawing features are required (on the contrary, the simpler/cheaper the better).

What should I consider? Since I own a MacBook, also writing on the built-in trackpad would be fine, but I've heard that the Inklet app slows down the computer in a very nasty way.

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far? Also please have a look at https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist and (with the appropriate changes) https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for ways to improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could purchase a Huion tablet from Amazon, I don't know if they are available in your region. They're quite cheap, I haven't personally tried them but based on the good reviews it looks like they do their job.

Here are two of them:

https://www.amazon.es/dp/B00DTPYWBG/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_0b9aCb8TDP9VH

https://www.amazon.es/dp/B00DM24HNE/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_di9aCb85MMQRV

There are also the Wacom tablets, I've used them before and I can say that they worked very well.

They can be expensive but there are a few cheaper ones like the Intuos S, I believe it was. It's specifically a drawing tablet but you could use it for writing.

Here it is:

https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets/wacom-intuos

And for the software, you could use Krita (a free painting app) or Photoshop CC. You could also find other apps in the Mac Store as well.

EDIT: There is a video I found:

https://youtu.be/T0uBv5od8xU

He's using Windows but there's a version of OneNote available for Mac. It converts the hand written equations into text. It's awesome!